# How to generate sample from unknow spatial process?

Tags: simulation, spatial, montecarlo

There is some unknown spatial process on square.
How to generate random sample of points on square if I have only 
distribution of average distance between points - any generic model or simple idea ?
What if I have distance matrix of some realization of such 
process ~500 observations would it be useful (matrix of distances between points from realization of process ) ?

Time dimension have no use here, I don't have any temporal data about the process.